# FullCalendar View More Button moving

Tags: fullcalendar

I have added a hack/add-on to allow me to limit the number of events which can appear on the Full Calendar plugin. This is where I have got the code from. https://github.com/lyconic/fullcalendar/tree/view-more

However, whenever I change the month or day the view more button moves and is hidden behind an event. Its really annoying and I don't know how to fix it.

Any advice?

Comment: does the button move without the hack?

Comment: Yes it does. It also moves when there is a hack, but when the hack is on the view more button moves. Also without the hack there is no view more button

Comment: better post your code for the view more button. as far as hiding is concerned you can try experimenting with the z-index css property